# Facebook App Review: confusion with share button

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, share, review

We have Facebook Share button in our app.

However i get this review notes: "on iPhone - Your app's Login with Facebook button needs to be easily recognizable and consistent with the Facebook brand. "

App users don't need authorization in FB, they only need to share posts.
Now this is a square shaped button. It looks like Facebook logo: white letter f on dark blue background. Sorry can't post images...

We are using ShareKit.
What's wrong with our button?

Thanks.